# how to restore telegram bot users id in Api-bot

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

how I can get all users who have sent msg to my old bot ?
I mean somehow recover their user id . name method please .
I do a lot research but cant make it .

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get past chats, or users that have previously `/start`ed your bot. It is up to the developer (you) to store the UserID of users for later use.

Comment: i saw someone do it via pyrogram . i dont know the right method name . i saw it happens and was strange to me . but he say to he doing that with pyrogram mtproto method